# Counting of natural numbers in the list

Tags: coq

I have non empty list of natural numbers. Want to define a function that finds the occurence of two natural numbers (n1 & n2) in the list.

Comment: Hint: you can do this because equality over natural numbers is decidable.

Answer (score 2):

It is not very clear what you want to do exactly - the title doesn't match very well the description. "Count" and "Find" is not the same thing. A first step in working with Coq is starting to use precise wording.

I guess you can either use the function `count_occ` from (https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Lists.List.html) twice or write a similar function which does two comparisons.

With the additional information, this should work:

```
Require Import List.
Require Import PeanoNat.
Import ListNotations.

Open Scope nat.

Search nat ({?x = ?y} + {?x <> ?y}).

Eval cbv in count_occ Nat.eq_dec [2;1;0;0;4;1;2;0] 1.
Eval cbv in count_occ Nat.eq_dec [2;1;0;0;4;1;2;0] 0.

Definition first_count_less (n1 n2 : nat) (l : list nat) :=
(count_occ Nat.eq_dec l n1) <? (count_occ PeanoNat.Nat.eq_dec l n2).

Eval cbv in first_count_less 1 0 [2;1;0;0;4;1;2;0].
```

Please note the `Search` command I used to find the equality function required by count_occ. It is worthwhile to read the section on `Search` in the reference manual (https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/vernacular-commands.html#coq:cmd.Search)

Comment: I want to count natural numbers n1 and n2.On the basis of count want to decide which one is greater.

Comment: Example count 1[2,1,0,0,4,1,2,0]<count 0[2,1,0,0,4,0,1,2,0].To prove above what hypothesis and generalize lemma  I should have ?

Comment: The sentence "to prove above" is not clear, because you have not stated a logical statement yet.